# Selenium Firefox 19 CSS Menu Click Not Working

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium, with an earlier combo of the `webdriver (2.28.0)` and `Firefox (pre-19)`, the following code worked.

```
driver.get("http://www.haemonetics.com/en");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("LOGIN")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Haemonetics")).click();
```

With `webdriver 2.31.0` and `Firefox 19.0.2` the code does not work and I receive a `NoSuchElementException` for the second findElement.

I tried using xpath which doesn't work for Firefox but does work for Chrome and IE, which are part of the same test suite.

Any thoughts or another way to accomplish the same thing? I would prefer to use the same code for the mentioned browsers.

Comment: Ok, here's an update from my end. The issue was an intermittent, but frequent, failure while running on and Azure virtual computer, which at times is fairly slow firing up a browser or connecting to an external site.  

I added in logic for WebDriverWait for the initial page to load complete with the "LOGIN" text to show up.  That seems to have helped substantially but it still fails on occasion, but just in Firefox.

I will post the results in more detail once I sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it was a typo on your part, but it should be "find_element" instead of "findelement", at least it's so in 2.31 to my knowledge.

Try

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("LOGIN")
```

if that doesn't work, post your HTML code so we can possibly construct a working Xpath.